# Proxy for Ruby HTTP traffic

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, proxy, terminal

I have a ruby script, that posts data to a URL:

```
require 'httparty'

data = {}
data[:client_id]     = '123123'
data[:key]           = '123321'

url = "http://someserver.com/endpoint/"
response = HTTParty.post(url, :body => data)
```

Now i am using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) for sniffing the HTTP traffic. This works great from the browser, but not from the terminal, where I run my script:

```
$ ruby MyScript.rb
```

How can I tell ruby or my Terminal.app to use the Charles proxy at `http://localhost:88888`

**Update** Another solution would be to see the request *before*  it is being sent. So that I would not necessarily need the proxy.

Comment: export http_proxy=localhost:88888

Comment: @Timmah Even tough this might work, I tried this but I don't see any traffic in Charles when I do that.

Comment: so u tried `export http_proxy=localhost:88888 && ruby MyScript.rb`?

Comment: Call `HTTParty::Basement.debug_output` before your request and HTTParty will print debug messages, including raw request and response

Comment: The port 88888 is wrong. they can't be more than 65535, maybe is 8888. Also export `http_proxy='http://localhost:8888'` is the right syntax

Answer (score 2):

Setting the proxy as [timmah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625688/timmah) suggested should work.

Anyway `88888` is not a valid port! I think you want to use `8888` (Charles proxy default port).

So the right commands would be:

```
export http_proxy=localhost:8888
ruby MyScript.rb
```

If your script was to use `https://` you would also/instead need to specify a HTTPS proxy like so:

```
export https_proxy=localhost:8888
```

Comment: Connect to http://localhost.charlesproxy.com/ instead. That's the official way to do it.

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/localhost-traffic-doesnt-appear-in-charles/